# Pandas creating and filling new columns based on other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with Time and values columns. I am trying to create two new columns 'START_TIME" and 'END_TIME'. It is medication related data and it is stored poorly in the database so I am trying to transform the table. 
In this case, the medication for a patient started at 2018-11-07 23:59:32 with a dose value of 80.o so, I want to capture that as the start time of the medication and end time is the first zero after the last value. That would be one round of medication. Whenever a new value starts it is considered as the second round of medication and I'd like to capture the start time and end time in the following way as explained earlier.

```
Time                          Values
2018-11-07 23:59:32            80.0
2018-11-08 04:35:09            80.0
2018-11-08 05:31:24            40.0
2018-11-24 18:29:30             0.0
2018-11-24 18:33:14             0.0
2018-11-26 17:39:31            20.0
2018-11-26 18:51:07            20.0
2018-11-26 21:04:35             0.0
2018-11-26 21:05:20             0.0
2018-11-26 21:13:44             0.0
2018-11-26 21:25:57             0.0
2018-11-29 02:19:57             7.0
2018-12-09 16:02:06             5.0
2018-12-09 16:33:03             2.5
2018-12-09 21:02:10             0.0
```

I believe it cannot be done with a simple for and if loop as I started with a simple step and it failed

```
for i in df['Values']:
    if i+1 != 0:
        df['START_TIME'] = df['TIME'].copy()
```

Expected DataFrame:

```
Time                     Values   START_TIME              END_TIME
2018-11-07 23:59:32       80.0    2018-11-07 23:59:32 
2018-11-08 04:35:09       80.0
2018-11-08 05:31:24       40.0
2018-11-24 18:29:30        0.0                            2018-11-24 18:29:30
2018-11-24 18:33:14        0.0
2018-11-26 17:39:31       20.0    2018-11-26 17:39:31
2018-11-26 18:51:07       20.0
2018-11-26 21:04:35        0.0                            2018-11-26 21:04:35
2018-11-26 21:05:20        0.0
2018-11-26 21:13:44        0.0
2018-11-26 21:25:57        0.0
2018-11-29 02:19:57        7.0    2018-11-29 02:19:57
2018-12-09 16:02:06        5.0
2018-12-09 16:33:03        2.5
2018-12-09 21:02:10        0.0                            2018-12-09 21:02:10
```

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC create the condition by using `diff`, then the value equal to -1 and 1 will be the end and start point

```
s=df.Values.eq(0).astype(int).diff().fillna(-1)
df.loc[s==-1,'START_TIME']=df.Time
df.loc[s==1,'END_TIME']=df.Time
df
Out[334]: 
                  Time  Values          START_TIME            END_TIME
0  2018-11-07 23:59:32    80.0 2018-11-07 23:59:32                 NaT
1  2018-11-08 04:35:09    80.0                 NaT                 NaT
2  2018-11-08 05:31:24    40.0                 NaT                 NaT
3  2018-11-24 18:29:30     0.0                 NaT 2018-11-24 18:29:30
4  2018-11-24 18:33:14     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
5  2018-11-26 17:39:31    20.0 2018-11-26 17:39:31                 NaT
6  2018-11-26 18:51:07    20.0                 NaT                 NaT
7  2018-11-26 21:04:35     0.0                 NaT 2018-11-26 21:04:35
8  2018-11-26 21:05:20     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
9  2018-11-26 21:13:44     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
10 2018-11-26 21:25:57     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
11 2018-11-29 02:19:57     7.0 2018-11-29 02:19:57                 NaT
12 2018-12-09 16:02:06     5.0                 NaT                 NaT
13 2018-12-09 16:33:03     2.5                 NaT                 NaT
14 2018-12-09 21:02:10     0.0                 NaT 2018-12-09 21:02:10
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create two mask (`m1&m2`) and with those masks conditionally create your `START_TIME` & `END_TIME` column:

```
m1  = (df['Values'].shift().eq(0) &  df['Values'].ne(0)) | (df['Values'].index == 0)
m2 = df['Values'].shift(1).ne(0) & df['Values'].eq(0)

df['START_TIME'] = np.where(m1, df['Time'], np.datetime64('NaT'))
df['END_TIME'] = np.where(m2, df['Time'], np.datetime64('NaT'))
```

```
                  Time  Values          START_TIME            END_TIME
0  2018-11-07 23:59:32    80.0 2018-11-07 23:59:32                 NaT
1  2018-11-08 04:35:09    80.0                 NaT                 NaT
2  2018-11-08 05:31:24    40.0                 NaT                 NaT
3  2018-11-24 18:29:30     0.0                 NaT 2018-11-24 18:29:30
4  2018-11-24 18:33:14     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
5  2018-11-26 17:39:31    20.0 2018-11-26 17:39:31                 NaT
6  2018-11-26 18:51:07    20.0                 NaT                 NaT
7  2018-11-26 21:04:35     0.0                 NaT 2018-11-26 21:04:35
8  2018-11-26 21:05:20     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
9  2018-11-26 21:13:44     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
10 2018-11-26 21:25:57     0.0                 NaT                 NaT
11 2018-11-29 02:19:57     7.0 2018-11-29 02:19:57                 NaT
12 2018-12-09 16:02:06     5.0                 NaT                 NaT
13 2018-12-09 16:33:03     2.5                 NaT                 NaT
14 2018-12-09 21:02:10     0.0                 NaT 2018-12-09 21:02:10
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `m1`: checks if the previous row **is** equal to 0 & the current row **not** equal to 0. Or if we are on the first row
- `m2`: checks if the next row **is not** equal to 0 & the current row **is** equal to 0